# Connecting to an Azure database using SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to an Azure database using SQLAlchemy in Python.

My code is the following:

```
engine_azure = \
create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{Server admin login}:{password}@{Server name}.database.windows.net:1433/{AdventureWorksLT}', echo=True)
```

[image]

I get the following message:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py:92: SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when using DSN-less connections
  "No driver name specified; "
```

Then I run the following code:

```
print(engine_azure.table_names())
```

I get the following message:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01S00', '[01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: The below answer worked for me!

Answer (score 28):

There are 2 issues with your connection string:

1. As per the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string): `The delimeters must be URL escaped` when using a pass-through exact pyodbc string.
2. And you do not specify the sql driver name either.

You can use the code below, which works fine at my side:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus \ # urllib.parse.quote_plus for python 3
(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yourDBServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbname;Uid=username@dbserverName;Pwd=xxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)

print('connection is ok')
print(engine_azure.table_names())
```

Test result:
[image]

And for the connection string, you can get it by going to azure portal -> your database -> connection strings(select the ODBC in this case):
[image]

Comment: when I checked the connection string on the Azure portal(like above 2nd screenshot), Azure showed me the email in place of username. 
A@outlook.com@APP_NAME
After I replaced the username with DB username, did it work as expected!
Hope others won't confuse like me :-)

Comment: I had to use a newer driver: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Answer (score 7):

This is what i use in Python3:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'Driver=%s;' % driver +
    'Server=tcp:%s,1433;' % server +
    'Database=%s;' % database +
    'Uid=%s;' % username +
    'Pwd={%s};' % password +
    'Encrypt=yes;' +
    'TrustServerCertificate=no;' +
    'Connection Timeout=30;')

conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + params
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
```

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if you provided information on the driver variable and what driver you installed. Check out the answer of Nebulastic.

Answer (score 7):

##### Step 1: Install Azure SQL DB Drivers

Install the new version of SQL DB Drivers using official documentation:
[Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=azuresqldb-current), [MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=azuresqldb-current), [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

***Major update to previous answers***: use the last supported version of DB driver `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` instead of outdated versions `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` or versions without explicitly defined a version, e.g. `SQL Server`.

##### Step 2: Install [sqlalchemy package](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/)

Just print in the terminal: `pip install SQLAlchemy`

##### Step 3: Wrapping specific DB logic in `AzureDbConnection` class

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Any, Iterable
from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
import urllib

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ConnectionSettings:
    """Connection Settings."""
    server: str
    database: str
    username: str
    password: str
    driver: str = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
    timeout: int = 30


class AzureDbConnection:
    """
    Azure SQL database connection.
    """
    def __init__(self, conn_settings: ConnectionSettings, echo: bool = False) -> None:
        conn_params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
            'Driver=%s;' % conn_settings.driver +
            'Server=tcp:%s.database.windows.net,1433;' % conn_settings.server +
            'Database=%s;' % conn_settings.database +
            'Uid=%s;' % conn_settings.username +
            'Pwd=%s;' % conn_settings.password +
            'Encrypt=yes;' +
            'TrustServerCertificate=no;' +
            'Connection Timeout=%s;' % conn_settings.timeout
        )
        conn_string = f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={conn_params}'

        self.db = create_engine(conn_string, echo=echo)

    def connect(self) -> None:
        """Estimate connection."""
        self.conn = self.db.connect()

    def get_tables(self) -> Iterable[str]:
        """Get list of tables."""
        inspector = inspect(self.db)
        return [t for t in inspector.get_table_names()]

    def dispose(self) -> None:
        """Dispose opened connections."""
        self.conn.close()
        self.db.dispose()
```

***Major update to previous answers***: do not forget to close the connection and dispose of the DB engine explicitly as soon as it stops being needed.

##### Enjoy!

Set connection settings and credentials using [Azure DB blade on Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.Sql%2Fservers%2Fdatabases):

```py
conn_settings = ConnectionSettings(
    server='<db_server_name>', 
    database='<db_name>', 
    username='<user_name>', 
    password='***')
```

Open DB connection:

```py
db_conn = AzureDbConnection(conn_settings)
db_conn.connect()
```

Test connection (for example, get available tables list), do other stuff, and close it finally:

```py
try:
    for t in db_conn.get_tables():
        print(t)
    # Do another DB-related stuff:
    # ...
finally:
    db_conn.dispose()
```

Answer (score 3):

Python3 snippet that I am using with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. Cost me some time to figure it all out, especially the driver version and params.

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

driver = "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
server = "<server-name>.database.windows.net"
database = "<db-name>"
user = "<db-user>"
password = "<db-password>"

conn = f"""Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={database};
Uid={user};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"""

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

engine.execute("SELECT 1")
```

Furthermore, I needed to install the following drivers/tools on macOS:

```
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions posted so far worked for me.

Instead, I had to specify Driver ({SQL Server}) which worked perfectly.

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=sqlhost.database.windows.net;DATABASE=pythonSQL;UID=username@sqldb;PWD=password56789")
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)
```

Source:

https://gist.github.com/timmyreilly/f4a351eda5dd45aa9d56411d27573d7c

Comment: Hi, about the simple SQL Server string, worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

For the following combination of dependencies

- Python 3.10.9
- SQLAlchemy 2.0.15
- pyodbc 4.0.39
- ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

the only thing that worked was to use the `URL.create()` from SQLAlchemy and pass in all the parameters from ODBC directly without creating a connection string first.

```
engine_str = URL.create(
    drivername="mssql+pyodbc",
    username=<username>,
    password=<password>,
    host=<server>,
    port=1433,
    database=<database>,
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "no",
        "Connection Timeout": "30",
        "Encrypt": "yes",
    },
)

engine = create_engine(engine_str)
```

Based on the ODBC connection string that Azure gave me:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=<server>,1433;Database=<database>;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I found the solution [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections).