# Python Script to read from multiple excel sheets and load to Azure SQL DB Tables

Tags: python, excel, azure

I Have a excel file with multiple spreadsheets and I need to use python script to read from this excel file each sheet and load the data into corresponding Azure SQL DB Tables.

1 Excel file 6 sheets = 6 Azure SQL DB tables

Appreciate any inputs on this requirement at the earliest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just for example, I created an excel file with two sheets, as the figure below.

[image]

There are two solutions for your needs to transfer data from excel sheets to the tables of SQL Azure.

1. To read the data of echo sheet via [`xlrd`](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) ([its document](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to generate the insert sql, then to execute these insert sqls via [`pyodbc`](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/), [`pymssql`](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/) or others. Here is my sample code for reading data from excel sheets in Python.

   ```
   import xlrd

   book = xlrd.open_workbook("samples.xlsx")
   sheet_names = book.sheet_names()
   for sheet_name in sheet_names:
       sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
       recs = ",".join(["('{0[0]}', {0[1]})".format(sheet.row_values(i)) for i in range(sheet.nrows)])
       insert_sql = f"insert into {sheet_name} (name, age) values {recs};"
       print(insert_sql)
       # Connect to execute the insert data sql via pyodbc, pymssql or others
   ```

   The result of the code above is.

   ```
   insert into Table_A values ('Peason1', 18.0),('Peason2', 19.0),('Peason3', 20.0),('Peason4', 21.0),('Peason5', 22.0),('Peason6', 23.0),('Peason7', 24.0),('Peason8', 25.0),('Peason9', 26.0),('Peason10', 27.0);
   insert into Table_B values ('Peason11', 27.0),('Peason12', 26.0),('Peason13', 25.0),('Peason14', 24.0),('Peason15', 23.0),('Peason16', 22.0),('Peason17', 21.0),('Peason18', 20.0),('Peason19', 19.0),('Peason20', 18.0);
   ```

   Meanwhile, please refer to Azure offical documents [`Python SQL Driver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`Quickstart: Use Python to query an Azure SQL database`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python) to know how to use pyodbc or pymssql to connect and query Azure SQL Database.
2. You can read the sheet data of excel file via `pandas`, and then to write data to SQL Azure via the function [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) through [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/) connection. Here is my sample code to read the sheet data of excel file to get pandas dataframe.

   ```
   import xlrd
   import pandas as pd

   file_name = "samples.xlsx"
   col_names = ["name", "age"]
   book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
   sheet_names = book.sheet_names()
   for sheet_name in sheet_names:
       df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=sheet_name, index_col=None, header=None, names=col_names)
       print(df)
       # Use df.to_sql with SQLAlchemy connection, that you can do it by yourself via refer to the pandas and SQLAlchemy documents.
   ```

   The result of the code above is.

   ```
          name  age
   0   Peason1   18
   1   Peason2   19
   2   Peason3   20
   3   Peason4   21
   4   Peason5   22
   5   Peason6   23
   6   Peason7   24
   7   Peason8   25
   8   Peason9   26
   9  Peason10   27
          name  age
   0  Peason11   27
   1  Peason12   26
   2  Peason13   25
   3  Peason14   24
   4  Peason15   23
   5  Peason16   22
   6  Peason17   21
   7  Peason18   20
   8  Peason19   19
   9  Peason20   18
   ```

   For connecting SQL Azure by SQLAlchemy, please refer to SQLAlchemy document [`Microsoft SQL Server`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html) and the other SO thread [Connecting to an Azure database using SQLAlchemy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704187/connecting-to-an-azure-database-using-sqlalchemy-in-python).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But my requirement is slightly different. Reading different sheets from excel work book will not be same structure. I mean not necessarily same number of columns and I don't want to merge into one dataframe and load into one table.Please clarify.

Comment: @Roxy Of couse yes, I don't know your real purpose and your data structure. But I think my sample code is enough for you to be changed by yourself to satisfy your real needs.