# pyodbc connection failing in sqlalchemy but working through direct pyodbc connection

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

Why does this workc(I get a result set back):

```
sql_server = 'myserver.database.windows.net'
sql_database = 'pv'
sql_username = 'sqladmin'
sql_password = 'password1'   
sql_driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+sql_driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+sql_server+';DATABASE='+sql_database+';UID='+sql_username+';PWD='+ sql_password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 3 SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID FROM PV_ALL_SUBMISSIONS_SL")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

But this fails:

```
import pyodbc
sql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{sql_username}:{sql_password}@{sql_server}/{sql_database}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
df.to_sql('PV_ALL_CLOSED_CASES_SL', con=sql_engine, if_exists='append')
```

Error is:

> OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could
> not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect);
> [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout
> expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A
> network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. (53)') (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

While I know one is doing a read and the other a write, my issue seems to be just establishing a connection one way vs another, when using the same connection details.  It isn't an Azure firewall issue as I am able to connect and run a select statment via the first method, but when using create_engine() of sqlalchemy, it fails to make the connection - but I am pretty sure the connection string is correct.

It is the same variables for server, user name and password being used in both connections.

I think the issue is that the real password as an "@" symbol in it, and so this interferes with the latter connection string.

Comment: Considering you are connecting the an Azure instance, have you checked your firewall rules for said instance? The port is not open to external IPs by default.

Comment: On a seperate note, a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: the select statement works, thats the confusion - it returns the records

Comment: @Larnu I appreciate the "TOP" statement, but at the moment I am just testing and there are 700,000 records in that table, I couldn't care less which 3 it returns!

Comment: *"the select statement works, thats the confusion"* That's not what the error says: `A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.`

Comment: @Larnu why is one connection working and the other not, this is what I am trying to work out.  It cant be a network issue if one works 100% of the time, and the other doesnt work 100% of the time.

Comment: Which means it's the latter, `Check if instance name is correct`. If the host is accessible, this means your connection details are incorrect.

Comment: @Larnu its the same variables being used in both code snippets for server name etc

Comment: Are those parameters URL escaped, per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716540/2029983)? If not, then the second connection string isn't valid; the parameter values might be the same, but the connection strings are *completely* different and have different requirements.

Comment: @Larnu will try, thanks. Don't have this trouble with cx_Oracle and sqlalchemy

Comment: Is that Oracle instance connected using a url as the host name..?

Comment: not sure I understand, its just a host name same as the azure host name above i.e. server.company.net same as Azure syntax

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Larnu, this worked:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
connection_string = f"DRIVER={sql_driver};SERVER={sql_server};DATABASE={sql_database};UID={sql_username};PWD={sql_password}"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
sql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)
```

I dont have to url encode when I use a cx_Oracle connection, but hey it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where pyodbc worked fine directly but not with SQLAlchemy.

For the following combination of dependencies

- Python 3.10.9
- SQLAlchemy 2.0.15
- pyodbc 4.0.39
- ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

the only thing that worked was to use the `URL.create()` from SQLAlchemy and pass in all the parameters from ODBC directly without creating a connection string first.

```
engine_str = URL.create(
    drivername="mssql+pyodbc",
    username=<username>,
    password=<password>,
    host=<server>,
    port=1433,
    database=<database>,
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "no",
        "Connection Timeout": "30",
        "Encrypt": "yes",
    },
)

engine = create_engine(engine_str)
```

Based on the ODBC connection string that Azure gave me:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=<server>,1433;Database=<database>;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I found the solution [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections).

Comment: Had the same problem - only this worked. I kept getting login failed, may have been because the password contained special characters and they were getting encoded when I used urllib3 solution to parse it to URL. The instruction from smackenzie also did not work for me (which uses odbc_connect).